# php http post response for web hook

Tags: php, post, push-notification

I'm trying to create a web hook notification. The documentation of the service i want to use requires that i specify a URL where POST requests can be performed. This URL will receive the following object, in json format, and must respond with a Status Code between 200-299.

```
{
  "type": "ping"
}
```

I don't know how to proceed making my server on **`localhost`** respond with a 200 status code. **`http_response_code(200)`** works well on live server but nothing seem to be happening on localhost.
Is there any way i can make it work with localhost?
I've included the link to the documentation [here](https://block.io/docs/notifications/php) (i hope it's not against the rule).

Comment: I would imagine that the API in question would offer a way for you to make a call to their API with the response. This is the scenario I am thinking: Something happens on the API side, the webhook is triggered, it calls your URI with type: "ping". At that point, you would call their API with the response back. Most likely in JSON format like so: {'response' : 200}. That is just an educated guess.

Comment: they didn't specify any way to call their API. Thanks for the input

Comment: I am thinking that you wouldn't have to send them the response. The webhook would know about the response. If it reached your URL successfully, it would be a 200 OK right off the bat. If the API is requesting a response back then I imagine that you would have to call it back somehow. Is this a well known API? Any documentation?

Comment: You are right. It worked perfectly without having to specify the header information. Thank you. I don't know if the API is well known. It has documentation albeit very sketchy (or maybe it's just me who's not understanding).

Comment: I am glad I could help. I posted an answer to your question. If that's the chosen one, please mark it best answer. thanks!

Comment: How do i mark the answer as best?

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green (see screenshot below): https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I still need a little help getting it to work on localhost. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Since that is a different issue, I would recommend that you mark this question resolved and open another one explaining your new issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I am thinking that you wouldn't have to send them the response.** The webhook would know about the response. If it reached your URL successfully, it would be a 200 OK right off the bat. If the API is requesting a response back then I imagine that you would have to call it back somehow. Is this a well-known API? Any documentation?

Answer (score 0):

The response code is in the response header, not in the content.

PHP defaults to a response code of 200, so if you don't mess with it at all, you should be good.

If you want to set a different response code (202 for example), just call:

```
http_response_code(202);
```

Or set the full header yourself:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted');
```

Comment: Thank you. But i didn't "mess" with it.

Answer (score 0):

Proper way to explicitly set 200 (or any other) status code with `http_response_code` function is just as following (don't echo or json_encode it):

```
http_response_code(200);
```

It should force webserver to use 200 status code in it's response. However, webserver could possibly ignore it. To check what response code your webserver sends, use `telnet` or any REST tool like `Postman`